# No bean class specified on bean definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am sorry that this is probably too vague and generel of a question. I am trying to bring up a huge legacy project with tons of spring wirings, and I am getting this error:

The bizzare thing is this error does not tell me on which xml, which bean id, the error occurs.

I certainly don't expect anybody to point me to where to fix.. **My question is, how do spring experts even debug this kind of uninformative error message?**

Yes, I understand it must be one of my xml bean was set wrongly. But shouldn't the error message make it easier for me to find out which bean?

Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

```
00:09:00.640 [main] ERROR com.xxxx.yyyy.zzzzzz.AppMain - Failed to initialize BLAH BLAH BLAH
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No bean class specified on bean definition
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:381) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:154) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
```

It's thrown by following piece of code. The init() methods takes in the spring xml files and do its wiring.

```
try {
    AppMain.init(args_);
} catch (Exception e) {
    _LOGGER.error("Failed to initialize BLAH BLAH BLAH", e);
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Are those the only stacktrace elements?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sorry I am not sure what you meant. These are from the end of my logs.

Comment: @CodeNoob Please post the top (relevant looking) stack trace in the log... not the bottom one.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is really already the top one.

Comment: Is it the end, or the top? Configure additional logging if this is the top.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch please see updated post. The rest of the error mesages aren't really interesting so I took the top portion of the last (and only) exception thrown in the logs. How do I configure additional logging of Spring?

Comment: What logging framework are you using? Anyway, you'd set the log level lower (e.g. debug). "org.springframework" is what you would normally to turn the logging level up (e.g. to error) for spring classes.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do spring experts even debug this kind of
>   uninformative error message?

I'd argue that the error message is very informative. It states that something has tried to put your application in an illegal state. In this particular example, your context was configured in a way where some bean's class is not specified. This is typically caused by forgetting to put a `class` attribute in a `<bean>` declaration.

Spring creates `BeanDefinition` objects for each bean in your context. These can be from your `<bean>` declarations or other XML elements or Java configuration elements (from `@Configuration`, `@Component`, etc.). Almost everything involved in a Spring `ApplicationContext` is a bean.

You can be pretty sure that Spring's infrastructure beans aren't to blame for this. Spring is an established framework with tons of work put into it and testing done before every release. The immediately obvious alternative is that somewhere in your code you forgot to specify a `class`. Did you, for example, try to make an `abstract` `<bean>` but forget to add the `abstract="true"`? Did you register a `BeanDefinitionParser` and create `BeanDefinition`s without a `class`? Did you create `BeanDefinitionPostProcessor` and remove `BeanDefinition` `class` values?

Those are the things I would start with.

Comment: Yes, but don't you think there should be an easier way to figure out **which bean**?

Comment: @CodeNoob Above the logs you've shown, it should have more logs saying: `Error creating bean with name...` if you are configuring your `BeanDefinition`s through `ApplicationContext` implementations.

Comment: I am facing an equally opaque unhelpful message with Grails which is built on Spring. I have used Spring for many years and despite knowing the principles of IoC which will seem very clear for simple examples, I still spend days trying to find out why the container will not instantiate a bean

Comment: @user1561783 Is there anything I can help with?

Answer (score 1):

That's a piece of the sources where it fails
You can try to set a breakpoint there in the Exception throwing. Or add the spring code rather than jar file and try to debug there.

```
public Class<?> getBeanClass() throws IllegalStateException {
        Object beanClassObject = this.beanClass;
        if (beanClassObject == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No bean class specified on bean definition");
        }
        if (!(beanClassObject instanceof Class)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Bean class name [" + beanClassObject + "] has not been resolved into an actual Class");
        }
        return (Class) beanClassObject;
    }
```